# Unique 2D Array but check against column value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ([0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => A
            [dept] => 0
         )
       [1]=>Array
        (   [id] => 2
            [name] => B
            [dept] => 0
          )
       [2]=>Array
        (   [id] => 1
            [name] => A
            [dept] => 1
          )
)
```

after applying, unique array function should check for duplicate value as id and check if dept >0 keep that, else remove duplicate array where dept=0

in above case result Array[1] and Array[2]

```
$final = array_values(array_combine(array_column($2DArray, 'id'), $2DArray));
```

above function gives me the unique array but I want to check against column value dept>0.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```
$output =array_values( array_reduce
                (
                    $2DArray,
                    function (array $carry, array $item) {

                        $key = $item['id'];

                        if (! isset($carry[$key])) {
                            $carry[$key] = $item;
                            return $carry;
                        }

                        $old = $carry[$key];
                        if ($old['dept'] < $item['dept']) {

                            $carry[$key] = $item;
                        }


                        return $carry;
                    },
                    array()
                ));
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it by `dept` then filter:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'dept'), SORT_DESC, $array);

$final = array_filter($array, function($v) {
                                    static $ids = array();

                                    if(in_array($v['id'], $ids)) {
                                        return false;
                                    } else {
                                        $ids[] = $v['id'];
                                        return true;
                                    }
                               });
```

And, as you should know `$2DArray` is not a valid variable name.